# permission denied to access server folder using ckeditor image upload

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Request you please help I hav einstalled ckeditor on core php also instaleed plugin "imagebrowser" and "imageuploader".

In config.js added

```
config.extraPlugins ='imageuploader';
config.extraPlugins ='imagebrowser';
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl ='/imagesNew';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl ='/imagesNew';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl ='/imagesNew';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl ='/imagesNew';
```

But browse button comes and error comes Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /imagesNew/ on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Please help

Comment: reformat your question. It's horrible formatted

Answer (score 0):

Hard to read... but the error message is quite self explanatory: you have a problem with permissions. The text of error is telling you even `You don't have permission to access /imagesNew/ on this server` so the problem is that. The question `why dont you have permissions to access that directory in server?` is the one that matters but we can not know the answer to that. Probably /imagesNew is not inside webroot tree folder and you're trying to access it with a non privileged test user.

Cheers.

Comment: I have given the folder permission 777.

Comment: Have you given those permissions to the folder from the operating system? Maybe you have permissions rules in your sever settings or your framework settings. That means that a user can access the folder within the linux/windows explorer but not from a PC client through the server. Try to find the word 'permission' or 'chmod' inside your server files.